# "'parity' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: parity, ropsten, windows, installation

I downloaded `Parity` installer from here : https://www.parity.io/ and then installed it on computer with OS Windows 8.1. Then even I restatred computer.

However, when I use following command:

```
parity db kill --chain ropsten
```

I receive following error message:

```
'parity' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Does it mean that `Parity` is not yet installed ? Or I need to do some complementary steps to finalise installation ?

Comment: Try `"C:\Program Files\Parity Technologies\Parity\parity.exe" db kill --chain ropsten` instead.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add `C:\Program Files\Parity Technologies\Parity` to the `path` environment variable.